# QueryFilter not working inside query operation in dynamodb

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

```
$response = array(
    "TableName" => "tableName",
    "AttributesToGet" => array('user_id'),
    "ConditionalOperator" => 'AND',
    "IndexName" => "indexname",
    "KeyConditions" => array(
        // Global Secondary HASH Key
        'id' => array(
            "ComparisonOperator" => 'EQ',
            "AttributeValueList" => array(
                array('S' => (string)$id)
            )
        ),
        // Global Secondary Range Key
        'date' => array(
            "ComparisonOperator" => 'EQ',
            "AttributeValueList" => array(
                array('S' => (string)$date)
            )
        ),

    ),
    'QueryFilter' => array(
        // no index 
        'status' => array(
            'ComparisonOperator' => 'EQ',
            'AttributeValueList' => array(
                array( 'S' => (string)"0")
            )
        )
    ),
);
$result = $client->query($response);
var_dump($result);
```

then response:

```
  array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { 
                    ["status"]=> array(1) { ["S"]=> string(1) "1" } 
                    ["user_id"]=> array(1) { ["S"]=> string(17) "20140425153549703" } } 
            [1]=> array(2) { 
                    ["status"]=> array(1) { ["S"]=> string(1) "0" } 
                    ["user_id"]=> array(1) { ["S"]=> string(17) "20140421162848857" } } 
         }
```

but i want to only "status"=0,

i have already used QueryFilter inside status condition but not working...

Comment: Are you using v2.6.1 of the SDK?

Comment: I would also be interested in seeing the LogPlugin output for the request to verify that the request is being sent correctly. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/faq.html#how-can-i-see-what-data-is-sent-over-the-wire

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and [Harshal Bulsara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2811189/harshal-bulsara) helped me.
Go to [Download AWS SDK for PHP](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/) and update your SDK.
Worked for me!